# Redirect to action in filterContext Result not working ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to redirect to a `Controller` in my `OnException` method, but the page is returning a blank view, and the link doesn't change to the page I redirected to. Please advise.

This is the code:

```cs
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
  if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;

  if (filterContext.Exception is PolicyInForceException)
  {
    PolicyInForceException pife = filterContext.Exception as PolicyInForceException;
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    filterContext.HttpContext.Server.ClearError();

    filterContext.Result = View(
      new RouteValueDictionary(
        new { area = "", controller = "quote", action = "Confirmation", id = pife.RequestId }
      )
    );

  }
  else
  {
    base.OnException(filterContext);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, to do a redirect, you want to return a [`RedirectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instance. The easiest way to do that is by calling any of the following [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) methods instead of [`View()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2):

- [`Redirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [`RedirectPermanent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirectpermanent?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [`RedirectToAction()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [`RedirectToActionPermanent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoactionpermanent?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [`RedirectToRoute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [`RedirecToRoutePermanent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroutepermanent?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

In your case, since you're redirecting to a specific action, you likely want to use the [`RedirectToAction()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method:

```cs
filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(
  "Confirmation", 
  "Quote", 
  new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
    id = pife.RequestId 
  })
);
```

That said, you could also use [`RedirectToRoute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) with code almost identical to your original:

```cs
filterContext.Result = RedirectToRoute(
  new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
    area = "", 
    controller = "Quote", 
    action = "Confirmation", 
    id = pife.RequestId 
  })
);
```

In your current code, by contrast, you're just returning a view for the current action—and the `RouteValueDictionary` you've constructed is being returned with that view as its view model, which is likely why you're seeing a blank page.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer!!

Comment: I tried to use RedirectToAction() but now I get a Server Error...

Comment: @MarisolFloresRivera: What is the error message you received?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 server error. Resource cannot be found.

Comment: @MarisolFloresRivera: Ah, in that case I'm assuming it's doing the redirect—but ending up at the wrong route? What's the URL look like that's delivering the 404? Assuming default routing conventions, I'd expect it to redirect you to `/Quote/Confirmation/123` (where `123` is your `pife.RequestId` value).

Comment: The route that is showing the error is /Home/123 wich is weird because I was in /Quote/Customer/123

Comment: @MarisolFloresRivera: I did change the name of the controller from `quote` to `Quote` which _may_ be causing a problem if your controller is named `QuoteController`? (I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, but it's worth pointing out). Do you get the same result if you instead use the `RedirectToRoute()` method and explicitly include the `controller` and `action` in the `RouteValueDictionary`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well but I keep getting the error =C

Comment: @MarisolFloresRivera: Are there any other required parameters on the action that it might be missing? It shouldn't matter, but you may also try removing the wrapping `new RouteValueDictionary()`—that _shouldn't_ really matter either way, but I'm grasping at straws since I don't know the specifics of your setup. The code supplied here _should_ be right, though, so it's also possible there's an ancillary routing issue this is exposing.